# How to create a spy class against the clone idiom in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++14, virtual, unique-ptr

Coming from the Java/PHP world, I am still new to C++. Some simple things to do in other languages are a bit trickier to do in C++.

My main issue is the following. Right now, I have a class (ie. "Something") for which the constructor is injected with a virtual class dependency (ie. a children of "Base"). Then, the constructor stores this injected instance in a `unique_ptr<Base>` class field (using the clone idiom). This works well at the application level, everything seems to works as expected. Here is the sample code:

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() = 0;
        virtual void sayHello() const = 0;
};

class Something {
    public:
        explicit Something(Base &base) { this->base = base.clone(); }
        void sayHello() const { base->sayHello(); }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Base> base;
};
```

But to make sure it does, I wrote unit tests to test its behavior. In those tests, I want to assert the injected dependencies methods are actually called. So logically, injecting a "spy" dependency should do the trick.

Here is what I did at first:

```
class SpyDerived : public Base {
    public:
        explicit SpyDerived() = default;
        SpyDerived(const SpyDerived &original) { this->someState = original.someState; }
        std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() override { return std::make_unique<SpyDerived>(*this); }
        void sayHello() const override { std::cout << "My state: " << someState << std::endl; }
        void setSomeState(bool value) { this->someState = value; }
    private:
        bool someState = false;
};
```

This is the main function I use to this this out:

```
int main() {
    SpyDerived derived;
    Something something(derived);

    derived.setSomeState(true);
    something.sayHello();
}
```

For obvious reasons, `someState` value on print is always `false`. I get that the `Derived` instances in `Something` is a new copy of `Derived` and no longer the one that was created in the main function.

So basically, what I am trying to achieve here is to have the `Something` class always use the `SpyDerived` instance created in the main function. Is there any way I could make this work. I am trying to avoid changing the design just for test purposes.

I am using MSVC 2015 to compile the code. Keep in mind that smart pointers, C++ idioms, copy/move constructors are fairly new concepts for me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The solution to you problem is obvious - you either use the pointer to the object (instead of cloning it) or use a reference to it. However, seeing the complexity of your code, I am sure you are aware of those solutions yourself, but have reasons to not use them. Hence what are those reasons?

Comment: @SergeyA I am using smart pointers in order to avoid memory management. And smart pointers don't play well with polymorphism in function signature. Basically, considering the following constructor signature `Something(unique_ptr<Base> ptr) {}`, using `Something(make_unique<Derived>(Derived()));` will simply not compile.

Comment: Why do you think so? Of course it will compile and work as expected, otherwise smart pointers would be totally useless. Btw, `make_unique<Derived>()` would suffice.

Comment: @SergeyA I stand corrected. It will compile (some slicing will occur, but it will compile).

Comment: No, there will no slicing. This usage is the primary usage of smart pointers, and it works with no slicing and exactly as expected.

Comment: @SergeyA so basically, I could pass a Derived smart pointer to the constructor (that expects a Base smart pointer), adding a get pointer function returning a Base pointer and cast it to a Derived object?

Comment: Smart pointers in this regards work exactly the same way as conventional pointers. Design your application as if you have a normal pointer (with no worrying about cleaning up) and drop-replace it with `unique_ptr`.

Comment: *"I am using smart pointers in order to avoid memory management."* - You don't really "avoid" it by using smart pointers. It's just a different, and arguably easier, kind of management. If you want to avoid it completely, use automatic storage duration whenever possible. That's the simplest and most beautiful thing in C++; strange enough, people coming from Java or other languages seem to have the greatest trouble with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, do you want to clone your instance, or simply reference that instance?

The clone idiom is **made** to copy the instance of a class, making the new instance independent of the old instance.

You are basically making this, in term of PHP:

```
<?php

interface Base {
    public function sayHello();
}

class SpyDerived implements Base {
    private $someState = false;

    public function sayHello() {
        echo 'My state: ' . $this->someState;
    }
}

class Something {
    public __construct(Base $base) { $this->base = clone $base; }
    public function sayHello() { $this->base->sayHello(); }
    private $base = null;
}

$derived = new SpyDerived;
$something = new Something($derived);

$derived->setSomeState(true);
$something->sayHello();

?>
```

You see this? `$base` is cloned. `Something::$base` is a *copy*.

So in PHP, what would you do to solve that problem?

Simple! Remove that clone, no copies!

---

Well, in C++, this is the same thing. If you have an object pointer and don't want to clone it, don't actually call the clone method.

We will change your class to, like PHP, contain a reference to the object. We will start by making `Something` contain a non owning reference:

```
class Something {
    public:
        explicit Something(Base& b) : base{b} { }
        void sayHello() const { base.sayHello(); }
    private:
        // we simply contain a reference to the base
        Base& base;
};
```

In C++, a reference does not own the object. If the object is destroyed, all reference pointing to that object will point to a dead object.

As you can notice, your tests stays the same and work:

```
int main() {
    SpyDerived derived;
    Something something(derived);

    derived.setSomeState(true);
    something.sayHello();
}
```

If you want `Something` be the owner of `Base`, then use `std::unique_ptr<Base>`:

```
class Something {
    public:
        explicit Something(std::unique_ptr<Base> b) : base{std::move(b)} { }
        void sayHello() const { base->sayHello(); }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Base> base;
};
```

Beware that the *ownership* of `base` should be transferred from the caller to the something class. That transfer is express through that `std::move` thing, because we are moving the *ownership* of that resource.

Then in your tests:

```
int main() {
    auto derived = std::make_unique<SpyDerived>();

    // We want to keep a non-owning reference of derived
    // The star (*) operator of std::unique_ptr returns a reference to the pointed object
    auto& derived_ref = *derived;

    // We transfer the ownership of  derived to the `Something`
    Something something(std::move(derived));

    // Since derived is a reference to the object pointed by our pointer,
    // It will affect the value we found in `Something`, because they are
    // both pointing to the same instance.
    derived.setSomeState(true);
    something.sayHello();
}
```

Since `Something` is owner of `derived`, the non-owning reference `derived_ref` will point to a dead object if `something` dies before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very well explained!

Comment: @GuillaumeLavoie consider accepting the answer if it really helps you then ;) if a better answer is added later, you can retract and accept the other one.